# Replace specific letter to a range numbers and search in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

Please help.

```
<form name="main" method="POST">                    
<input name="search" type="text">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Whenever the user enter X or Y or Z this value will read as range 0-9

i need to capture the value in database using php and mysql

When the user enter the value in search input text ex. "XX1YYZ"

i need to read the letter "X" equal to range "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

i need to read the letter "Y" equal to range "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

i need to read the letter "Z" equal to range "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

where "X" is not be equal to "Y" and "Z

where "Y" is not be equal to "X" and "Z

where "Z" is not be equal to "X" and "Y

Sample data in database

1233557

1255661

1288119

7711458

666788

3344556

For example i enter "12XXYYZ" in text input

the output should be "1233557" and "1255661" and "1288119"

because it equal to the database value

Its kinda complicated ryt? Please help

This is i have so far but the number should not equal from each result and should search to database value

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$searchtext = $_POST['search'];
foreach (range(0, 9) as $n) {

$trans = array("X" => $n, "x" => $n, "Y" => $n, "y" => $n, "Z" => $n, "z" => $n);
if (strtr($searchtext, $trans)){

echo '<br>' . strtr($searchtext, $trans);       
}
}
}
```

Comment: You should add code you wrote to achieve this goal

Comment: i put my initial code but that is all i have i don't know what next step

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are attempting to do?
With more explanation we can likely get you more assistance.

Comment: I will put this on the quick search, when the user type xXX or YYY or ZZZ on the search text all number with triple like 777,222,333 will capture to database and show in a table page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a solution:

First get from the database the numbers that gets the basic selection, by replacing XYZ with ???

```
select * from [table] where [field] like '12_____';
```

This should limit your selection.

Next step is in PHP, below in psuedo code:

```
foreach ($row)
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($char in $filter) {
    $i++;
    if ($char == 'Z')
      if ($Z == empty) 
        $Z = $field[$i]
      else
        if ($field[$i] != $Z)
          break;
     // repeat for Y
     // repeat for x
   }
   if (x == y or y == z or x == z)
     continue;
   addtoresult($row);
 }
```

Comment: That is my initial problem, i don't know how to filter all equal records in my database with input XYZ or ???

Comment: stringreplace(x,?,stringreplace(y,>,stringreplace(z,?,filter)));

Comment: what i mean is, for example to your query "select * from [table] where [field] = '12?????';"                                                      how to run it in sql and should equal it to 1233441

Comment: Woops sorry i ment. Where [field] like '12_____'. Changed in the answer. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp